# JQuery tooltip doubts/questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I'm developing a last.fm widget, and one of the requisites is, for each track that is displayed of a certain tag (genre), a small button must be present. This is so that a tooltip appears when the button is clicked, showing more information about a certain artist, their albums, and their most popular track. This is all done with Ajax requests.

My page is live [here](http://phpdev.dei.isep.ipp.pt/i101524/lastfm-widget/index.html). I have managed to get everything working except the tooltip, which I'd like to get showing when someone clicks the little 'i' button icon next to each track.

Some questions arise, though:

1. I will need to fetch the data from last.fm with Ajax for the tooltip and then position the tooltip so that it shifts automatically according to the button that's pressed.

My code that shows the 'i' icon next to each track is just this (positioned relatively with CSS after):

```
<dd class="lfm_info"><img src="images/info.png" /></dd>
```

The Ajax function creates X buttons depending on how many tracks have been selected. However, from what I've been reading, only one tooltip should be created, outside any tags (but inside the `<body` tag, of course) and this should be shifted programmatically. Is this the correct approach?

I've also noticed that there seems to be a huge amount of JQuery plugins to handle tooltips, and I've not managed to get even one to work because of issue 1) - I don't know how to position them, so they show up in random places of my page if I place the tags outside my repeating track `<div>`'s, and **don't even show up at all** if I place it inside those said tags. Which do you think is the best plugin to handle/create tooltips? I'd like something clean, and that handles automatic positioning easily.

Thank you for reading, and I hope someone may be able to assist me.

Comment: The easier approach would be to put a <div class="tooltip"> container inside .lfm_info container for each track. Then dynamically populate it on click. I am going to assume you already know about AJAX request and leave that part out.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do AJAX requests and handle the data. My doubts concern more about how to display said tooltip on screen and have it shift (and change content, naturally) depending on the button that's clicked.

Comment: Would it be a full screen tool tip (similar to a modal box), do you have any examples on how it should look like?

Comment: No, it should be one of those tooltips that generally occur on hover/click of a certain element. Something like this: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#ajax maybe with a black style, but that's easy to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example. It's actually really simple, but obviously without knowing the full user scenario there will be issues with it that will require you to tweak.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dj9xS/3/

The problems:

1. Doesn't detect sides of window, so tool tip could potentially be outside of window.
2. There is no event to make tool tip disappear without clicking on "i" image again.

HTML:

```
<style>
    dl { width: 300px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .lfm_info { position: relative; width: 16px; }
    .tooltip { display: none; background: black; width: 120px; position: absolute; bottom: 20px; left: 50%; margin-left: -68px; color: #fff; padding: 10px; }

</style>
<dl>
          <dt class="lfm_art">
          <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Red+Hot+Chili+Peppers/_/Californication" title="Clique para ouvir Californication no last.fm" target="_blank"></a>
          <img src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/42739473.png" alt="Artwork de Californication"><img src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/42739473.png" alt="Artwork de Californication"></dt>
        <dd class="lfm_song">2. Californication2. Californication</dd>
        <dd class="lfm_artist">Red Hot Chili PeppersRed Hot Chili Peppers</dd>
    <dd class="lfm_info"><img src="http://phpdev.dei.isep.ipp.pt/i101524/lastfm-widget/images/info.png"><div class="tooltip"></div></dd>
      </dl>


<dl id="ajaxReference">
          <dt class="lfm_art">
          <a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Red+Hot+Chili+Peppers/_/Californication" title="Clique para ouvir Californication no last.fm" target="_blank"></a>
          <img src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/42739473.png" alt="Artwork de Californication"><img src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/42739473.png" alt="Artwork de Californication"></dt>
        <dd class="lfm_song">2. Californication2. Californication</dd>
        <dd class="lfm_artist">Red Hot Chili PeppersRed Hot Chili Peppers</dd>
    <dd class="lfm_info"><img src="http://phpdev.dei.isep.ipp.pt/i101524/lastfm-widget/images/info.png"><div class="tooltip"></div></dd>
      </dl>
​
```

jQuery:

```
$('.lfm_info').click(function(){
    var toolTip = $(this).children('.tooltip');

        // Get data using AJAX
        // Not sure how you are requesting data, maybe by unique ID? Need to put into each track dl to 
        // reference. e.g. $(this).parent().attr('id');

    // If success populate into tooltip on $(this).children('.tooltip')
        // $(this).children('.tooltip').text(ajaxData);   

        toolTip.text('Hello World');

    // If fail  
        // return false;

    if(toolTip.is(':visible')){
        toolTip.fadeOut(500); 
        return false;    
    };       


    // Check if any other tooltips are visible    
    if($('.tooltip').is(':visible')) {
        $('.tooltip').fadeOut(500, function(){        
            toolTip.fadeIn(500);        
        });  
    } else {
        toolTip.fadeIn(500);    
    };       

});​
```

I hope this is helpful for you though.

Comment: This is great amount of help, thank you so much! If I want it to disappear naturally (without having to click again), is there an event for that? Or should I just use hovers insteads of clicks (so when hover is false it hides it, for example)? And as for controlling the sides of window, I believe that can be done with verifying the dimensions somehow (maybe using offsets?). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I tried using your JFiddle in my code, but it's not triggering the click event when I click the icons (I even put an alert in there to see if something was happening). There must be something blocking it, because I can't for the life of me figure out what it is. I've literally copied and pasted the code and the classes all seem right.

Comment: Strange, do you have any errors on the page? Have you edited the HTML also?

Here is a more updated and re-factored version: http://jsfiddle.net/dj9xS/5/

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far, but it simply won't work on my page. I've tried everything - copying & pasting your JS code into my .js file, removing all CSS from the relevant part and copy-pasting yours (broke the formatting obviously, but it still didn't work). I don't seem to have any errors in my HTML, but it still isn't picking up that event.

Comment: It wasn't picking up the event because I forgot to put your code inside the callback for the AJAX request. It only works AFTER all the html has been created by the AJAX function. Thanks + accepted answer due to helping out greatly. :)