# When adding item to cart I want to show a quick thing that says "item added to cart" and goes away in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Net website, basically its a shopping website. I have one requirement that when adding item to cart I want to show a QUICK thing and then disappears.

According to me it will be better to show tool-tip on Cart Div when I click on "Add to cart" Button and then set its fadeout time will work.

But I am new to jQuery and programming so I am not sure how can I do that.

I have checked some links but I am not very much sure about these:

[JQuery tooltip doubts/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964847/jquery-tooltip-doubts-questions)

[jQuery UI Tooltip Widget auto close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048189/jquery-ui-tooltip-widget-auto-close)

Can anyone please give me some examples or suggestions so that I can do this.

Thanks

Comment: Your request is too broad. Try doing some of your own research first and then narrow your question down a bit, so that you can get specific help.

Comment: what you had tried so far

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" id="myButton">Click Me!</button>
<div id="msg"></div>


$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $("#msg").html('Added to Cart').delay(500).fadeOut();
});
```